# What computer brands and processors do Ubuntu 18.04 LTS support

Tags: 18.04, hardware

I have been considering building a laptop and installing Ubuntu 18.04-3 LTS onto it. I don't know what brand of computer to use, and I do not know what processor(s) to use. Can anyone give me a list of models that are compatible with Ubuntu, and their prices?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04-3 works with all common hardware released before mid-2019.Newly-released hardware can sometimes be problematic. Some specialty hardware (mostly video cards, GPUs, wireless) is made by manufacturers that do not provide Linux support for their hardware - avoid those.

Comment: Thank you. Suppose I got an NVidia Graphics card that is incompatible. Could I install drivers for this brand?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Use the Search box at the top of the page and look for Nvidia questions.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Check out Ubuntu hardware compatibility:
  http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Hardware-HOWTO/
- Linux Supported Processors:
  http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Hardware-HOWTO/cpu.html
- Also Check out Laptops that will run Linux fine:
  https://www.linux-laptop.net